# Automatically fill middle repeated div horizontally

Tags: css

I have essentially three divs.

```
<div id="headerLeft"></div>
<div id="headerMiddle"></div>
<div id="headerRight"></div>
```

With the following CSS

```
#headerLeft
{
background-image: url("topLeft.png");
height: 88px;
width: 329px;
float:left;
}
#headerMiddle
{
background-image: url("topMiddleRepeat.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:relative;
height: 73px;
float:left;
color: white;
min-width:100px;    
padding-top: 15px;
}
#headerRight
{
background-image: url("topRight.png");
float: left;
height: 87px;
width: 47px;
float:right;
}
```

I need the middle div to repeat horizontally to fill the rest of the header's space. I can't set the width of the div manually because this html will be inserted into other pages of unknown widths.

I've tried setting the width to 100% but that just fills up the whole line and pushes the leftHeader above the middleHeader and the rightHeader below the middleHeader.

Here is the page I am currently trying to manipulate. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1501628/web/ipiphony.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect for #headerMiddle. It should be background-repeat:repeat-x; not 'x-repeat'.

Comment: @Dan thanks. I updated the syntax, but my original problem still remains :(

Comment: have you tried some of the solutions below?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do it i don't think it's possible, What i would do is this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerLeft"></div>
    <div id="headerMiddle"></div>
    <div id="headerRight"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#header {
  background-image: url("topMiddleRepeat.png"); /* In the container */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 88px; /* the height of your images */
}
#headerLeft {
  background-image: url("topLeft.png");
  height: 88px;
  width: 329px;
  float:left;
}
#headerMiddle {
  height: 73px;
  float:left;
  color: white;
  min-width:100px;    
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#headerRight {
  background-image: url("topRight.png");
  float: left;
  height: 87px;
  width: 47px;
  float:right;
}
```

That way your background will cover the header. Another option is to nest the divs and set the background to eack one and use padding for the sides.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerLeft">
        <div id="headerRight">Your text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#header {
  background-image: url("topMiddleRepeat.png"); /* In the container */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 88px; /* the height of your images */
}
#headerLeft {
  background-image: url("topLeft.png");
  height: 88px;
  padding-left: 329px;
}
#headerRight {
  background-image: url("topRight.png");
  height: 87px;
  padding-right: 47px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**Update the following styles:**

```
#header {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 85px;
}

#headerLeft {
background-image: url("topLeft.png");
height: 88px;
width: 329px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

#headerMiddle {
background-image: url("topMiddleRepeat.png");
height: 73px;
color: white;
padding-top: 15px;
margin-left: 329px;
margin-right: 47px;
}

#headerText {
position: absolute;
left: 260px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#headerRight {
background-image: url("topRight.png");
height: 87px;
width: 47px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

If there are still issues, I recommend uploading the styles and HTML to jsfiddle.net so everyone can have an active play.